# How to change the name from "me" to recipient names of the same subject heading?

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to see how I can find emails with same subject heading sent to different people through the "sent" setting on Gmail?

All I can see when I click "sent" with a specific subject heading is

"me" rather than "to: the names of the recipients"

Is there a way to fix this?